# How can I list hidden administrative shares using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, security, powershell, network-share

I'm trying to write a script that will audit shared folders on a few HIPAA-sensitive servers. I'm getting a list of shares just fine using `gwmi Win32_Share`, however when I go to get the permissions on each share using `gwmi Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting`, the hidden administrative shares are not listed.

I realize that's for obvious reasons, it's not like the permissions change, but I would like some kind of indication that this is in fact an administrative share. Currently I'm using a try-catch block to handle the error and kicking out a 'permissions could not be found' message.

Is there any way I can list ONLY hidden administrative shares using PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try (change "." to your remote computer name):

```
[String]                                   $Local:strComputerName  = ".";
[System.Management.ManagementBaseObject[]] $Local:arrShares        = @();
[System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]   $Local:objShare         = $null;

$arrShares = Get-WMIObject -class "Win32_Share" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $strComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 2147483648 };
if ( $? ) {
    foreach ( $objShare in $arrShares ) {
        # List attributes (other attributes include AccessMask, AllowMaximum, Description,
        # InstallDate, MaximumAllowed, Status and Type).
        Write-Host -Object ( "Name        : {0}" -f $objShare.Name );
        Write-Host -Object ( "Path        : {0}" -f $objShare.Path );
        Write-Host -Object ( "Caption     : {0}" -f $objShare.Caption );
        Write-Host -Object "";
        } #foreach
} else {
    Write-Host -Object "ERROR.";
} #else-if
```

Comment: Ah, guess I should have been more clear. I need to list _only_ administrative shares, so I can differentiate between those and hidden shares.

Comment: Looks like adding `-Filter "type=2147483648"` to `gwmi "Win32_Share"` will display only admin shares. `"type=0"` will show only disk drive shares.

Comment: Updated - see end of Get-WMIObject line...

Comment: I tried this script and changed the `"."` to `"HisComputer"` and the console says "ERROR"